# Migrate standard object standard field newly added picklist values

Tags: force.com, picklist, standard-objects, migration

when using Ant Force.com Migration tool,can newly added picklist values to standard object's standard picklist fields which come out of the box be migrated by just including the standard field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can simply migrate by providing appropriate defination in package XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
 <members>Account.Industry</members>
 <name>CustomField</name>
 </types>
<version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

The above shows how you will migrate industry picklist field for Account

Answer (score 0):

The example given is out of date now as of API 38. See StandardValueSet.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br9y

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? Link only answers tend to break over time!

Comment: Currently it is NOT possible to migrate standard field picklist values using ant migration tool or changeset, please support the idea in the answer above.

Answer (score -2):

you can migrate the picklist values of the standard fields by adding the standard value sets from dreamfactory. It is the best method I have found so far.

Comment: Is dreamfactory a product you are affiliated with?